# Open XML SDK 2.5 can't install because it is not already installed?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, installation, openxml-sdk

i'm having some trouble installing OpenXML SDK for Microsoft office. I have downloaded the .msi from the MSDN website, run it but before any installation wizard shows, i get this window popping up:

[image: Error message]

It seems to want to install itself before it will install itself.. I have OpenXML on my other PC and this installed fine with no issues and have used the tool for a project.

I have .NET 4.6.2 installed on my machine.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: There are 2 separate installers on the MSDN page - the SDK and the tools. From the error message you are seeing it looks like you are trying to install the tools but in order to do so you need the SDK installed first.

Comment: aha! That its - i think it was because i downloaded tool .msi but not the full .msi. Silly error - thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: No worries, I've added it as an answer for completeness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 separate installers on the [OpenXml 2.5 MSDN page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30425) - the SDK and the tools. From the error message you are seeing it looks like you are trying to install the *Tools* but in order to do so you need the *SDK* installed first.

[image]

Comment: This link to MSDN is broken now.

Comment: I found an archive website for the download

 https://web.archive.org/web/20190116000204/https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425